# Get the most recent time series message from Time Series Insights

Tags: api, get, endpoint, azure-timeseries-insights

Is there an TSI-Endpoint that provides the most recent message of a time series that arrived from e.g. an iot-hub? In my current situation I have to poll a certain period of time (for example now to 30 seconds in the past) and I wonder if there is a better way to do this?

Comment: For this particular use case you might be better off just peeking at the latest message using the event hub endpoint?

Comment: Thanks - this approach needed a little bit of effort but in the end fitted my needs exactly!

Comment: Awesome, great to hear! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no endpoint that lets you query only the last event. You can use GetEvents and query over the last 30 seconds, like you said, or peek the last message from the Event Hub/IoT Hub.